# Angular RxJS HttpPost without subscriptions

Tags: angular, rxjs, http-post, rxjs-observables

Working in `Angular` with `RxJs` all data retrieval is done with `Observables` and the `async` pipe in the html.
This is the correct approach to avoid `Subscriptions` in the `Component`.

How can i achieve the same when posting data to the server? I have no view that can await this call but i want to remove the `.subscribe()` from my Component.

Comment: what's the follow up UI behaviour after a successful post?

Comment: What is the reason behind _"This is the correct approach to avoid Subscriptions in the Component"_? What is wrong with subscriptions in the component when they are closed when the component is destroyed?

Comment: if you don't need the result in the component, you could move the `.subscribe()` inside of the service method, so you don't have to deal with it every time you call the service method

Answer (score 3):

The `async` pipe will subscribe to any Observable passed to it, so in principle it works for POST calls exactly the same as for GET calls.

Assuming you're storing your POST call in an Observable in your component you can subscribe to it using `async` in your template:

```
// In component:
postCall = this.http.post(url, payload);

// In template:
<div>{{postCall | async}}</div>
```

That being said, there's nothing wrong in using `subscribe()` within your components. You just need to correctly handle unsubscribtions when your component gets destroyed: there are several patterns (and some libraries) to do that.

Answer (score 2):

What does your post do and what's the UI representation of a successful post? an error? That's all the question you need to answer before getting the correct answer.

If you're in the classical situation of a collection of object, with a CRUD logic on it, and you want to use a reactive paradigm, which is the most common paradigme that removes most of the subscribe calls in component and replace those with Async Pipe, what you'll need is an Observable of the collection of object that you want to display. You'll then have a "display" logic which will use an Async Pipe to display the data from that observable and an update the collection logic that will "translate" the user's action into update of the collection observable. The whole logic behind the reactive paradigm is to clearly separate the two logics. It simplifies a lot every other aspect.

Once you're there, the question is how to interact with the backend server. When you want data it's simple: call the api, get the list of object, put it in the collection observable. When you want to post/put/patch/delete it's a little bit more complicated but not that much. First you need to decide if you'll work in an optimistic or pessimistic way. In optimistic you basically add the created object (or update/delete) to the observable collection as soon as the user create it without waiting for the backend response. You'll then have a very fast user interface but you'll have to code all the rollback logic. In pessimistic you call the server first, then if the server response is 201/204 you update the collection accordingly. And it there is an error you'll catch it directly. Less code, slower interface.

The important things to understand here is that: 1) You need an internal representation of the object, independent from the backend server, that's the collection observable. 2) You need to separate the display logic to the user action logic. That makes things a lot easier.

Note that this whole logic is implemented by stores libs. As a store will add some boilerplate code (a ton!) it's a tradeoff: If the application is complex, the added difficulty of the store can be counterbalanced by the added benefits. If the application is simple, a service with some subjects will do the job.

PS: you should look for reactive programming angular on google, you'll find some articles explaining how it works, like this one for example: https://www.sipios.com/blog-tech/reactive-programming-rxjs-observables-angular

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule that says don't use subscriptions in the component. Just use them less. For example how would you create a HOT (active) observable from the http request unless you call subscribe() on it? There is nothing wrong with calling subscribe() in a component, there are just nicer ways to handle observables that using the Subscription model.

Comment: observables of httpClient are COLD

Comment: until you make them HOT by subscribing to them

Comment: as far as i understand a hot-observable is emitting values independend of any subscriber, a cold observable starts producing (emmiting) values at the point where some subscriber is added.